# "Подстать": слитно или раздельно?

Tags: орфография

Вообще-то, я написал слитно (подстать чему-то), но Ворд почему-то подчеркнул. И я теперь начинаю сомневаться: правильно ли писать слитно?

Answer (score 4):

Раздельно, тут Ворд прав.
Но вообще-то Вы правы в том, что Ворду надо поменьше доверять. Если он что-то подчеркивает, надо проверять в словарях.
http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%EF%EE%E4%F1%F2%E0%F2%FC&all=x

Answer (score 3):

Наречные сочетания предлогов-приставок без, для, до, под, при, про с формами имен существительных (в том числе не употребляющимися вне этих сочетаний), напр.:
под боком, под вечер, под гору, под дых, ПОД СТАТЬ - пишутся РАЗДЕЛЬНО. (Полный академический справочник под редакцией Лопатина). Так что Ворд в данном случае прав.